# Is it possible to set several display names for one application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-settings

I have several websites, each of website have unique name, but they use just one facebook app, so, when user want to share post, and he is unauthorized - he sees "Log in to use your Facebook account with ApplicationDisplayName".
Is it possible to change "ApplicationDisplayName" to name of website?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your reply! If I correct understand, for this realization, I must create application for each website?

Comment: Yes, if you want a unique display name per site, then you need one app per site. (Be aware though, that you will get different app-scoped user IDs across those apps then. So if you need to match users across sites based on the app-scoped ID, you will need to take additional steps.)

Comment: @CBroe probably I can hide applicationDisplayName?

Comment: No, you can not hide anything displayed in the login dialog either.